# unclassified data points in libsvm?

Tags: svm, libsvm, svmlight

SVM tutorials state that if a data point falls in the area surrounding the separating line (in the margin) - it isn't classified. How is this implemented in libraries like SVMlight and libsvm?

Answer (score 1):

For two-class classification, we usually assume that their targets are `+1` and `-1` respectively. Then we find the maximum-margin hyperplane by a QP solver. Because of soft margin (see the term **C** in SVM}, some samples exist in the margin.

But that's not problem.
We can determine the class that positive values as `+`-class and negative values as `-`-class

To sum up,
Even if the samples are trained as `+1` and `-1`, SVM classifies `+`-class when `>= 0` or `-`-class when `< 0`